# Progress event listeners to load thumbnails one at a time

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am working on around 40 Large images each of size 9000KB.
i have below code ,all images are loading at a time which makes my screen to freeze,I want that my control will wait until the first image is successfully progress then loads completely then move on to the next one.any idea is helpful..

```
//dropping around 40 images 

dropbox.addEventListener("drop", dropUpload, false);


function dropUpload(event) {
    noop(event);

    var dropMethod = event.dataTransfer;
    var classicMethod = event.target;

    var dropedFiles = (dropMethod == undefined) ? classicMethod.files: dropMethod.files;
    for ( var i = 0; i < dropedFiles.length; i++) {
        addFilesToUpload(dropedFiles[i]);

    }
}

function addFilesToUpload(file) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"), div = document.createElement("div"), img, progressBarContainer = document
            .createElement("div"), progressBar = document.createElement("div"), tBody;
    li.appendChild(div);

    progressBarContainer.className = "progress-bar-container";
    progressBar.className = "progress-bar";
    progressBar.setAttribute("id", "proBar_" + (indexN++));
    progressBarContainer.appendChild(progressBar);
    li.appendChild(progressBarContainer);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = function(event) {
        alert("couldn't read file " + event.target.error.code);
    };
    // Present file info and append it to the list of files
    fileInfo = "<div><strong>Name:</strong> " + file.name + "</div>";
    fileInfo += "<div><strong>Size:</strong> " + parseInt(file.size / 1024, 10)
            + " kb</div>";
    fileInfo += "<div><strong>Type:</strong> " + file.type + "</div>";
    div.innerHTML = fileInfo;

    if (reader !== "undefined" && (/image/i).test(file.type)) {
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("class", "thumb");
        img.setAttribute("id", "img_" + (indexN++));
        reader.onload = (function(img, li) {
            return function(evt) {
                img.src = evt.target.result;
                img.file = file;
            };
        }(img, li));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    reader.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            progressBar.style.width = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100 + "%";
        }
    }, false);

    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        progressBarContainer.className += " uploaded";
        progressBar.innerHTML = "";
    }, false);

    tBody = getTableBodyLayout(img, li);
    document.getElementById("images_table").appendChild(tBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `addFilesToUpload()` to take a callback when the file is done and change `dropUpload()` to initiate one at a time.

```
function dropUpload(event) {
    noop(event);

    var dropMethod = event.dataTransfer;
    var classicMethod = event.target;

    var dropedFiles = (dropMethod == undefined) ? classicMethod.files: dropMethod.files;
    var filesDone = 0;

    // local function to process the next file
    function next() {
        if (filesDone < dropedFiles.length) {
            addFilesToUpload(dropedFiles[filesDone++], next);
        }
    }
    // do the first one
    next();
}

function addFilesToUpload(file, doneCallback) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"), div = document.createElement("div"), img, progressBarContainer = document
            .createElement("div"), progressBar = document.createElement("div"), tBody;
    li.appendChild(div);

    progressBarContainer.className = "progress-bar-container";
    progressBar.className = "progress-bar";
    progressBar.setAttribute("id", "proBar_" + (indexN++));
    progressBarContainer.appendChild(progressBar);
    li.appendChild(progressBarContainer);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = function(event) {
        alert("couldn't read file " + event.target.error.code);
    };
    // Present file info and append it to the list of files
    fileInfo = "<div><strong>Name:</strong> " + file.name + "</div>";
    fileInfo += "<div><strong>Size:</strong> " + parseInt(file.size / 1024, 10)
            + " kb</div>";
    fileInfo += "<div><strong>Type:</strong> " + file.type + "</div>";
    div.innerHTML = fileInfo;

    if (reader !== "undefined" && (/image/i).test(file.type)) {
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("class", "thumb");
        img.setAttribute("id", "img_" + (indexN++));
        reader.onload = (function(img, li) {
            return function(evt) {
                img.src = evt.target.result;
                img.file = file;
                // call the callback to tell the caller that this file is done now
                doneCallback();
            };
        }(img, li));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    reader.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            progressBar.style.width = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100 + "%";
        }
    }, false);

    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        progressBarContainer.className += " uploaded";
        progressBar.innerHTML = "";
    }, false);

    tBody = getTableBodyLayout(img, li);
    document.getElementById("images_table").appendChild(tBody);
}
```

---

If you want to wait to proceed to the next image until each image has loaded, then you could change the `reader.onload` handler to this:

```
    reader.onload = (function(img, li) {
        return function(evt) {
            img.onload = function() {
                // call the callback to tell the caller that this file is done now
                doneCallback();
            };
            img.src = evt.target.result;
            img.file = file;
        };
    }(img, li));
```

Comment: @user2117386 - I do not understand your question.

Comment: In the above scenario the progress bars are loading one after the other, but not the image . the image will be loaded slowly after may be 2-3 progress bars of different images are complete.The problem is that while images are being loaded my whole memory is being utilized and mozilla is crashing. do you have any idea why its happening like that...

Comment: @user2117386 - no I don't understand what the problem is.  One or two images in memory should not cause a browser crash.  Do you want to wait for an image to load before you proceed to the next file?

Comment: if i try to load more than 20 images its crashes in mozilla.so i think the problem may be because images and progress bars are loading simultaneously for different images.if i remove  below 2 lines its not crashing but at the same time its not showing thumbnail too.    img.src = evt.target.result;
img.file = file;

Comment: @user2117386 - when you say "crash", to you mean the entire browser crashes and stops working and the browser must be restarted or do you mean the current web page just has an error and stops loading/working properly?  Browsers can manage thousands of simultaneous image requests (they have a max number they request at any given time and then queue up the rest) so there must be something else going on here.  I need to understand what is actually happening to the browser as "crash" isn't enough of a description.

Comment: when i check in my task manager memory usage reaches slowly from 122,000K to 380,000K(cpu utilized 100%) and when it reached above this point the entire browser crashes

Comment: @user2117386 - Are you exhausting your physical memory on your computer?  How much RAM do you have in your computer?  What else are you running at the same time?  Do you have a virtual memory swap disk configured?  380,000k is not super high (only 380MB).  My browser can consume that much in some normal operations.

Comment: RAM is 512MB, but when i tried to upload 40 large images through http://www.flickr.com/ , the memory usage always stays constant around 160,000K, that is never crashing..

Comment: @user2117386 - That is very low RAM.  Is there virtual memory swap disk configured?  Your situation is more complicated than I can fully follow just with these code snippets (without seeing a working example that illustrates the precise problem), but I added a variation to the end of my answer that waits for the image to load before advancing to the next one.  I have no idea if this is actually the issue or not, it's just a guess based on what you're asking for.

Comment: @user2117386 - FYI, I don't even understand why you create the `img` object.  You don't seem to do anything with it.